# I'm looking for a single-word to describe someone who complains to others who are far worse off than themselves

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single-word to describe a particular behavior often seen in people diagnosed with b-cluster personality disorders. It usually involves complaining due to never feeling satisfied with anything and not feeling thankful for what they have. However, the person doing the complaining often complains to those who are far worse off than they are.

Here are a few examples of this behavior:

1) A rich CEO complains to a poor person who's struggling to make a living about not having enough money.

2) A rockstar who records in a huge studio complains to an amateur musician who records in their closet about their huge studio being a "closet".

3) A film star complains to an amateur actor who can't seem to catch a break about not having enough fans.

Comment: I believe in the zeitgeist, "tone-deaf" is the term used for that.

Comment: The [tag info](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) for single-word requests says "INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used." I recommend you [edit] your question accordingly, to avoid it being closed.

Comment: @Chappo I think his examples serve to show his usage rather well. They're not sample sentences, but at least offer a context.  This isn't closable on that particular basis.

Comment: @DavidM I disagree. Without an example sentence, one answer might be "That CEO is {adjective}" (as you've chosen to interpret it in your own answer), another might be "That CEO is a {noun}", a third might be "That behaviour is an example of {psychiatric term}". Does the OP require a term that *only* applies to "people diagnosed with b-cluster personality disorders"?

Answer (score 0):

That person may feel too afraid to tell those that are deemed to be on par or above their 'level'.  So they might feel more comfortable telling those that are deemed 'less than' by said person, in which case...'ogre' might be a good word.  But insecure is probably better.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. This answer is more of a psychological evaluation than an answer about the English language. Please attempt to answer the question with a single word suggestion, then provide context and definition for that word.

Answer (score 0):

[**Insensitive**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/insensitive) is the catch-all phrase for this type of behavior.

It implies that someone is not being sensitive to their audience.  The speaker is showing a lack of decorum or tact by not considering who they're addressing.

[**Tactless**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tactless) and [**Tone-deaf**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tone-deaf) also work well here for the same reasons.